# Как сформировать Kendo grid второго уровня

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo

Есть Kendo Ui Grid.
Хотел сделать у него для каждой строки возможность вызова подстроки.
смотрел как делается тут http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/hierarchy

Подгид делаю так:

```
function detailInit(e) {
        $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: kendo.format("/Home/Metod"),
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {name:"parameter"}
                    }
                }
            },
            columns: [
                        { field: "name", title: "name1", width: "50px" },
                        { field: "name2", title: "name2", width: "50px" }

            ], resizable: true
        });
    }
```

Вызываемый метод в контроллере, который должен вернуть данные для подгрида:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult findSchemasInfo(string name) {
```

//.... формируем коллекцию объектов

```
        return new JsonResult()
        {
            Data = new
            {
                //возвращаем коллекцию объектов (список), у каждого из     //которого 2 текстовых поля - name1 и name2

            },

        };
    }
```

Вопрос следующий - как отправить из контроллера коллекцию объектов и как её принять в js скрипте (что в нём неправильно)?

Comment: в Дожо залейте свой код, так не разобрать в чем проблема

Comment: извините, не знаю что такое Дожо. Залил на файлобменник - http://my-files.ru/wddon2

Comment: http://dojo.telerik.com/ вот дожо

Comment: мм, не совсем понимаю как залить туда код. Кроме того, есть ещё метод ASP MVC контроллера. Его там вроде нельзя вставить же. Возможно есть какой-нибудь другой способ объяснить что непонятно объяснил в вопросе?

Comment: Ну у вас проблема же не в методе MVCшном, значит можно его опустить. Что касается дожо, то выберите фреймворк, слева должен быть ваша разметка и скрипт, потом нажимет Run, справа увидите результат.

Comment: увидел, только как и ожидал там ничего нет в подгриде. Вот - http://my-files.ru/y3zb7v

Comment: вы бы лучше сюда ссылку на ваш пример выложили, что бы другие могли  отладить код

Comment: http://dojo.telerik.com/@Dmitry05/onUga - вроде так

Comment: Ну вы не правильно пользуетесь кендошкой. Как я понимаю, вы хотите сделать иерархическую табличку, верно?

Comment: да, верно, её. Пользуюсь неправильно, согласен ). Вот и хотел у знающих людей узнать что не так делаю

Comment: Ну например, зачем вы таблицу рисуете разором, когда вы должны просто указать тег в описании таблицы, и описать ее ЖСом? Сделайте все как в примере и не выдумывайте всяких странных вещей :)

Comment: я думал, что это не повлияет на формирование грида 2-го уровня. Или влияет?

Comment: как минимум то что вы сделали совершенно не нужно.

Comment: нашёл решение. Bezarius, спасибо за терпение.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по вашему [коду](http://dojo.telerik.com/@Dmitry05/onUga) вы пользуетесь `kendo` не правильно - вы пытаетесь создать заголовки таблицы используя `razor`, в то время как нужно просто сконфигурировать таблицу через js, указав все необходимые параметры, такие как заголовок таблицы, сортировки, фильтры, модель данных, источник данных и прочее.

Кстати если вы пользуетесь C#, то вы можете использовать ASP .NET реализацию Kendo UI, вам как начинающему будет проще с ней пользоваться. Однако по своему опыту замечу, что js реализация куда более гибкая.

Вот пример иерархической таблицы на ASP .NET взятая из прмеров Телерика:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.EmployeeViewModel>()
        .Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(e => e.FirstName).Width(110);
            columns.Bound(e => e.LastName).Width(110);
            columns.Bound(e => e.Country).Width(110);
            columns.Bound(e => e.City).Width(110);
            columns.Bound(e => e.Title);

        })               
        .Sortable()
        .Pageable()
        .Scrollable()
        .ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:600px;" })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(6)
            .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_Employees", "Grid"))            
        )        
        .Events(events => events.DataBound("dataBound"))
)

<script id="template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.OrderViewModel>()
            .Name("grid_#=EmployeeID#") // template expression, to be evaluated in the master context
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(o => o.OrderID).Width(110);
                columns.Bound(o => o.ShipCountry).Width(110);
                columns.Bound(o => o.ShipAddress).ClientTemplate("\\#= ShipAddress \\#"); // escaped template expression, to be evaluated in the child/detail context
                columns.Bound(o => o.ShipName).Width(300);
            })
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .PageSize(10)
                .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_Orders", "Grid", new { employeeID = "#=EmployeeID#" }))
            )
            .Pageable()
            .Sortable()
            .ToClientTemplate()
    )
</script>
<script>
    function dataBound() {
        this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
    }
</script>
```